# multiple /tellraw reactions from same command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make something and I want a `/tellraw` to activate and when the player clicks on it multiple things happen. What I mean is when they click on the text like 5 `/setblock` commands activate. I can't figure out how do do this. I have tried just putting multiple `clickEvent`s in but it does not work. Is this even possible?

I'm playing Minecraft 1.7.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I let player click text to use a command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316754/how-can-i-let-player-click-text-to-use-a-command)

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as you are on 1.7.10 I would say the easiest way is to make the /tellraw command activate a /setblock command that puts a redstone block in an area that activates the five command blocks. Yes, it's that simple. I used to use this when I was trying to make a map back in 1.7.10 all the time! This is the easiest way to do it in 1.7.10 from what I know. I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry. i wasn't very clear when i made my question. what i meant is when the person clicks on the /tellraw thing it activates 5 setblock commands relative to the players cordinates.

Comment: Can you please show the command you are using in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of the server, does it run bukkit and do you know how to write Java? If all of the above are yes, I think it would be easiest to create a small plugin that achieves this. If you don't, the best is to look at the other answers.

It is very easy to create a command listener  that dispatches more commands when it activates. You can then use a `/tellraw` to call this command. Here is some example code:

```
package my.pkg;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mycommand")) {
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(sender, "command1");
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(sender, "command2 with arguments");
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(sender, "command3");
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is listen for `/mycommand`. If someone does this command (by clicking a link from a `/tellraw` message for example), the code will automatically fire the commands `/command1`, `/command2 with arguments` and `/command3`. These commands can be any command, like the `/setblock` you mentioned.

For more information on creating plugins, here is a (slightly older, but still viable) video:

.